# Is there objective proof that Jo Jorgensen stopped Trump winning, like a right-wing Ralph Nader?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, libertarianism, third-party

[Breitbart is pushing the theory](https://www.breitbart.com/2020-election/2020/11/10/libertarian-jo-jorgensen-difference-joe-biden-donald-trump-in-key-swing-states/) that if Jo Jorgensen hadn't run, Trump would have won (assuming that he didn't).  Is this correct?  Is there objective proof that all (or enough) of her votes would have been for Trump if she hadn't run, such that he would have won?  And that all of her voters would have voted, as opposed to not voting?

I'm not convinced on either count.

Comment: I'd also challenge the premise that Gore lost because of Nader, necessarily. But that's fodder for another question (that's probably already been asked).

Comment: While many libertarians favour Republicans because of the guns, small government and low taxes, others avoid them because of the drug war, immigration control, racism and "family values".

Comment: @Paul Johnson: And I strongly suspect that, like me, a good many voted against Trump not because of his policies (or those of the Republicans), but because of his personal characteristics.

Comment: Exit polling quite clearly shows nader voters stealing from clinton in the swing states, I have no idea why so many are convinced it was the other way around. It seems like one of those things that people kept repeating because they've heard it before without ever checking if it was correct or not.

Comment: This may as well be summed up as, "if people voted differently, could the outcome have been different?" Well, yes, yes it could! Pointless...

Comment: Ah, the stolen vote fallacy is back.

Comment: I have to challenge the general premise of the question. People don't go to poll stations just to vote for the most suitable candidate on the list, they go because they feel like they have support a certain candidate. If Jo Jorgenson weren't there, there is a good chance they wouldn't go and vote. If it were in Turkey, the question might make sense because election turnout there is spectacularly high compared to USA but it doesn't make any sense for USA.

Comment: So?  If Nader hadn't run in 2000 Gore might have won.  Does that mean Bush didn't?  What's the point of the question if the election followed established laws and rules?

Answer (score 88):

**TL;DR:** It's a virtual impossibility, but mathematically possible. If Trump won a large majority of Libertarian votes, he could have won key states. Four states are in play. One combination gives him a tie and a possible win in the House. Winning all four gives him a win. The rest are Biden wins.

---

With all races called, Biden has 306 electoral votes, needing to lose 37 to tie the election and send it to the House, and lose 38 to lose outright.

The most obvious states to flip are Pennsylvania (20), and at least one 16-vote states (Michigan, Georgia) plus Nebraska's 2nd congressional district (Omaha, 1 vote), **OR** Pennsylvania, Arizona (11), and Nevada (6). Wisconsin (10) is also a candidate.

I'm assuming this question is something like "*If only Trump and Biden were on the ballot, would Trump have won after Jorgenson's voters realigned?*"

I have rounded because results<sup>1</sup> aren't final. "%B" is the percentage of the Libertarian votes (`L votes`) which would need to go to Trump to tie with Biden in the the state, assuming *Biden gets none of the other votes*.

However, for Trump to win, he needs B% of the L vote, *and* he needs the remainder of those voters to be split evenly between him and Biden so they cancel out. "Split" is the minimum Trump needs, *assuming Biden gets the rest* (`Split = %B+ 0.5 * (100 - %B)`).  If Trump were to win "Split"% or higher of the Libertarian vote, then he would win in that state.

Values are left out where the L vote was smaller than the margin.

| State | EV | Margin | L votes | %B | Split |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AZ | 11 | 11,000 | 51,000 | 22% | 61% |
| GA | 16 | 14,000 | 62,000 | 23% | 62% |
| NV | 6 | 37,000 | 14,000 |  |  |
| MI | 16 | 148,000 | 60,000 |  |  |
| NE-2 | 1 | 22,000 | 6,000(2) |  |  |
| PA | 20 | 54,000 | 78,000 | 69% | 85% |
| WI | 10 | 21,000 | 38,000 | 55% | 78% |

Arizona and Georgia (27) doesn't give him the win, but Pennsylvania or Wisconsin as well would. Trump would have to take Libertarian voters 80-20 to win, which strains credulity, but isn't out of the question.

However, this USANews [article](https://www.usnews.com/news/top-news/articles/2020-11-06/libertarian-spoiler-in-us-presidential-election-not-a-chance-experts-say) says:

> There is disagreement over which of the two main parties takes a bigger hit when a Libertarian is in the race. Boaz pointed to a 2016 CBS exit poll that showed that 25% of Libertarians who voted that year would have supported Democrat Hillary Clinton if there had been no Libertarian candidate. For Trump that figure was 15%, while 55% said they would have not voted.

If we surmise that 50% of L votes wouldn't have voted if there was no Libertarian candidate on the ballot, Trump can no longer win Pennsylvania or Wisconsin. He can only win Arizona and Georgia if he takes about 73% of the voting Ls (37% of the original number). This is more plausible, IMO, but he would not win flipping only Georgia and Arizona (27).

| State | EV | Margin | 0.5 L votes | %B | Split |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AZ | 11 | 11,000 | 25,500 | 43% | 72% |
| GA | 16 | 14,000 | 31,000 | 45% | 73% |
| PA | 20 | 54,000 | 39,000 |  |  |
| WI | 10 | 21,000 | 19,000 |  |  |

**Conclusion** It is mathematically *possible* for Trump to have won if there was no L candidate. However, if Biden wins any sort of a significant fraction of the former L voters - or they don't turn out, as is common for them - it makes it virtually impossible for Trump to win. If turnout patterns reflected 2016, it is *impossible* for Trump to win based on the L vote.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Data from [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/11/03/us/elections/results-president.html), except for NE-2 which came from [Cook Political](https://cookpolitical.com/2020-national-popular-vote-tracker).

<sup>2</sup>: Votes listed as "other," not for Jorgensen specifically, but it doesn't matter either way.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116179/discussion-on-answer-by-azor-ahai-him-is-there-objective-proof-that-jo-jorgens).

Comment: This is a well-researched answer, but (and this is more a critique of the question) the hypothesizing doesn't stop there. If the Libertarian party didn't stand a candidate, not only could their voters pivot to Trump / Biden / not voting, it's also likely that other third parties would be encouraged to ramp up fundraising and fill the void

Comment: @waltz True, which makes this hypothetical the friendliest situation for Trump and even then it's pretty unlikely.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I had a hard time following the explanation of what each column represented, so once I worked it out, I reworded some things there.  If I mis-explained anything or you object, feel free to edit or revert it.

Comment: @Bobson Thanks, there was a lot of back and forth last night that got moved to chat. I tweaked your wording, but otherwise looks good.

Comment: Extrapolating 2016 voting patterns to 2020 seems like a stretch, but I guess it's the best we can do.

Comment: @Barmar Eh, Trump is still Trump, and I don't see Biden as being very different along the dimensions that Ls care about.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- The difference is that in 2016 no one knew what a Trump presidency would be like, and now we do. There's more than just politics to this election.

Comment: @Barmar I mean nothing he's done has been a surprise ... I would disagree with that assessment. This is pretty much exactly what anyone who was paying attention would have expected.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I knew he would be a bad President, but I was hopeful that he might step up or at least lean on advisors. IMHO, to most outside his base he was far worse than we could have imagined. Plus there's the whole pandemic disaster.

Comment: If you're interested, [here](https://reason.com/2020/10/12/how-will-reason-staffers-vote-in-2020/) is another (very small) data point which suggests to me that without Jorgenson many libertarians would simply have stayed home.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Is reason.com a big libertarian site?

Comment: Yes, that is their thing.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Wow there are some crazy notions on that page